# Interfacing with a custom PCI from windows

Tags: c++, c, pci

I'm trying to write a program that can read from a bunch of sensors, make decisions on a windows computer, then write to some actuators (e.g. valves). This is all already done on an existing system and program but we want to do something different and so are starting with a new program on the windows computer from scratch.

The reading and writing of sensors etc is done through a custom-made PCI from the manufacturer and basically I'm not sure how to read and write to the registers on the board. I've done projects with Raspberry Pis and other microcontroller+PCBs but this one's a bit new. The original program was written in c++ if that helps.

Any general or specific info on interfacing directly with PCIs from windows systems would be great, and if this isn't enough info let me know and I'll provide more. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). In particular, your question as currently worded is too broad and asking for pointers to external resources is also off topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to access the hardware via a driver provided by the manufacturer. Many manufacturers don't document how to access their drivers directly by the end user code. Instead, they provide an API library (in an SDK) that the users call into to operate the PCI device.

It'd help if you'd post a link to the device you're using - that way we could look at what's bundled with it and help you decide whether it's worth the effort. If the manufacturer is non-cooperative, this may be a relatively hard thing to do. You may have more luck not using the PCI card and e.g. getting some EtherCAT I/O modules, using an open source EtherCAT master library, and connecting your application to the I/O modules via a simple network card. That would be way more supportable, and very resistant against obsolescence, as the EtherCAT I/O is not going away anytime soon, and your code could be fully portable if you used a portable app development framework like Qt or wxWidgets. You could then run it on PCs, macs, Raspberry PI - and it'd do the same thing and look mostly the same. It's not a pipe dream - I maintain some code that does pretty much just that and it's a viable approach. As long as your requirements are "soft" realtime, it's bound to work. If you need hard-realtime, you'll need to limit yourself to Linux with realtime extensions, and access the network interface (using the ECAT master library) from a realtime thread. It's still more developer-friendly than, say, using a PLC with EtherCAT Master support - those usually use CODESYS under the covers, and that's basically just spreading misery :(

In my experience, supporting some custom motion-control PCI cards and such ends up being semi-rewarding, since you get to do some reverse engineering all too often, and that's a good challenge, but it's a dead-end ultimately. If the card has no API/SDK available, then it's best assumed that the manufacturer is dumping it, and all your work will be for nothing when it goes out of support or becomes unobtainium. It's best to rely on viable industry standards, and on interfaces that have multiple vendors on equal footing. EtherCAT I/O is dime a dozen, almost. You can use e.g. the (freely downloadable) TwinCAT to explore the I/O module's functionality and prototype stuff, and then implement it in your own code using the ECAT master library, perhaps with help of WireShark when needed.